# Correct Syntax using Web3 for Contracts with multiple parameter methods

Tags: web3js

Working with a contract that has multiple parameters just wondering what the correct syntax would be for.

```
// creation of contract object
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);

// initiate contract for an address
var myContractInstance = MyContract.at('0x78e97bcc5b5dd9ed228fed7a4887c0d7287344a9');

var result = myContractInstance.myConstantMethod('myParam');
console.log(result) // '0x25434534534'

myContractInstance.myStateChangingMethod('someParam1', 23, {value: 200, gas: 2000}, function(err, result){ ... });

//This is where I'm not sure???????
myContractInstance.myStateChangingMethodMultiParm('someParam1', 23, 'someParam2', 23, {value: 200, gas: 2000}, function(err, result){ ... });
// Or
myContractInstance.myStateChangingMethodMultiParm({'someParam1':23, 'someParam2': 23}, {value: 200, gas: 2000}, function(err, result){ ... });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your Solidity function is like so:

```
function myStateChangingMethodMultiParm(uint param1, uint param2) ()
```

Then you call it like so:

```
myContractInstance.myStateChangingMethodMultiParm(
    23,
    24,
    { from: myAccount, value: 200, gas: 2000 },
    function (err, result) {});
```

Normally you can omit the `gas:` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

This one works fine:

> myContractInstance.myStateChangingMethodMultiParm('someParam1', 23, 'someParam2', 23, {value: 200, gas: 2000}, function(err, result){ ... });